# How to add custom CSS and JavaScript file for wp- admin dashboard (backend)

Tags: wp-admin

I want to add some CSS and JavaScript to the WordPress dashboard but only for my custom post type design and some script functionality.

Can any one suggest to me about how to include my custom CSS and JavaScript files for backend users?

Comment: Hi@Vivek you need to add css and javascript in your theme?

Comment: @Samyappa yes  how it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have use `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook to include css and js in your backend.

So instead of:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name');
```

Use:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'your_function_name_for_admin');
```